# Second Hard Drive for MongoDB using directoryperdb

Tags: mongodb, symlink

Does anyone have any experience using `directoryperdb`? I can't find very many examples of its usage and would like to run my thought process past some knowledgeable people first :)

I've got a near terabyte database, and want to add another on a separate hard drive. I can't mess it up since reintegrating my data takes hours.

I currently have:

- `--dbpath` as `/home/mongo`
- A new nice empty hard drive mounted on `/hd/newhd`

My process is as follows:

1. Lets call the existing database `old` and the new one `new`.
2. `mkdir /home/mongo/old`
3. `mv /home/mongo/* /home/mongo/old/`
4. Symlink `/home/mongo/new` to `/hd/newhd/newmongodb`
5. `vim /etc/mongod.conf` ~ and set `directoryperdb = true`
6. restart mongod and start inserting data into a new db called `new`

Does this look OK? Will it just automatically recognize the new folders and continue as normal?

---

Edit1: According to this: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/mongodb-commits/frAjIDG08Mc the `mongod.lock` file should be in `/home/mongo`. What about the journal or _tmp directory?

Comment: If you say that dbpath is `/home/mongo/new` I see no problem, of course MongoDB knows nothing of symlinks it just uses the OS' own lookup features

Comment: `dbpath` is still `/home/mongo`. I've moved the database into two different subfolders (one a symlink) and I hope `directoryperdb` will recognize this. My question is does this look correct to someone who has done this in the past?

Comment: I have no experience but I found some links: it seems it would work but I found: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1379 dunno if this will effect you but thought I would paste it, you can actually see an example of some one who does exactly the same as you here: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-7999. Also this could help in moving https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/mongodb-user/wPbzG0cFFpg it seems you should just move the db files themselves to the sub folder and leave everything else in the root. HTH

Comment: might try moving this question to dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: I took the plunge and it worked - see Answer :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK so I took the plunge and it worked fine~! :)

I'm now successfully saving data into the `new` db symlinked to the second HDD.

The only edit is that don't bother moving the `journal` folder into the db sub-directories as it will just be recreated in the main `--dbpath`

Hopefully someone else will find this post useful.